# ipmi_si module is missing and can't be found

Tags: centos, ipmi, ipmitool, bmc

Looked all over google and stackoverflow; can't find an answer to this "simple" problem.

Background: I have a Supermicro server running centos 6.5 kernal 2.6.32-431.29.2.el6.x86_64.  I have been trying to configure IPMI, and after much troubleshooting, I realize that the problem is likely due to the ipmi_si (and ipmi_msghandler) module not being present.  I believe that the only way to obtain these modules is by upgrading the kernel:

```
[blah@localhost]$ yum provides "*/ipmi_msg*.ko"
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.mirror.constant.com
 * epel: ftp.osuosl.org
 * extras: linux.cc.lehigh.edu
 * updates: mirror.metrocast.net
kernel-debug-2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64 : The Linux kernel compiled with extra debugging enabled
Repo        : base
Matched from:
Filename    : /lib/modules/2.6.32-    504.el6.x86_64.debug/kernel/drivers/char/ipmi/ipmi_msghandler.ko

kernel-2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64 : The Linux kernel
Repo        : base
Matched from:
Filename    : /lib/modules/2.6.32-       504.el6.x86_64/kernel/drivers/char/ipmi/ipmi_msghandler.ko

...etc
```

Agreed?  I'd rather obtain these modules without upgrading the kernel.  Furthermore, assuming that I must upgrade the kernel, can someone confirm that the reason for this is simply that those modules are not "compatible" with the current kernel?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your system (`Centos 6.5 kernel 2.6.32-431`) `ipmi_si` module is not present because it's built-in in the kernel. Double check with the following command:

```
[root@host ~]# cat /proc/kallsyms  | grep init_ipmi_si
ffffffff814fb086 t init_ipmi_si
ffffffff81d26f50 t __initcall_init_ipmi_si6
```

`init_ipmi_si` is the initialization function of the `ipmi_si` module. Same applies to `ipmi_msghandler` (look for `ipmi_init_msghandler`). So, your issues must be related to something else.

Have you loaded `ipmi_devintf` instead? Do you have a `/dev/ipmiX` device?